# one-page website with soft scroling and static navi bar

Tags: html, css

can you help me to find solution?

i am a novice in site building so have a trouble with positioning.

[Here will be my site](http://almazini.comxa.com/#map)

And here is css for it.

```
#navigation {
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 5%;
right: 5%;
width: 90%;
color: #4b5dd2;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);

}
#navigation a {
font-size: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: grey;
} 

/*####################################################################################################*/

#page1{
position: inherit ;
top: 70px;
left: 5%;
right: 5%;
width: 90%;
height: 1000px;
/* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;    
}

/*####################################################################################################*/

#page2{
position: inherit;
top: 1070px;
left: 5%;
right: 5%;
width: 90%;
height: 1000px;
/* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;    
}
```

Can you please advice me the right attribute settings?

I am trying to achieve that navigation bar is always on top, and site itself is scrolling above navigation bar. In other words if navigation takes 5% of screen i would like pages with information be only in other 95%.

Now it seems that pages are behind navigation

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a z-index to allow things to have a set hierarchy when they overlap. Set the z-index of your top-bar to something like `z-index: 10;` and your body `z-index:2;` (note these #s are very arbitrary, default is 1 though for everything).

Also note z-index is not universal, it compares itself to elements it is UNDERNEATH/above only. Ie:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
                content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="d">
    content
</div>
```

if you give z-indexes to c, it will not interact with z-index info on d because they are not "related." **AND**, if you want z-index of C to relate to z-indexes of a and b, you must define them for a and b.

---

Here's an example

**HTML**

```
<head>
 <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="/styles/main_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="top_bar">menu item 1 2 3 4 5</div>
       <div id="centering_tool">
           <div id="body">
               <div class="body_content">paragraph 1</div>
               <div class="body_content">paragraph 2</div>
               <div class="body_content">paragraph 3</div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#container { widthL100%;}

#top_bar {
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5;
} 

#centering_tool { margin: 0 auto;}

#body {
    width:800px;
    height:1000px;
    z-index:3;
}

.body_content {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:pink;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

try this to get an idea

Comment: not sure i understood about z-index! can you use html from my site? thank you

Comment: `<head>` tags fyi is not for literal "headers" but stuff like including scripts or stylesheets. move ALL website body content into `<body> <!--your site here--> </body>` tags. I will update my post

Comment: seems that not working:( body_content should be with digits? and where are links in navigation bar? 
What I am trying to do is a site e.g. 4000px divided into 4 divs 1000px each. And navigate between these divs using static bar which will be always on top

Comment: it's just a very rough template to illustrate concepts to you, not doing your site design... i think you just need to google this more, it sounds like you've done next to no googling